# Decode Response from API in PHP

Tags: php, json, decode

Hi guys is there a way in php where in I can print this response prettier? For example, Print only the firstname, lastname, middlename of the response content.

Here's the response i got from the API 
[image]

I tried decoding the response with this code but still failed to get the key and values

```
    $students["mi"];
var_dump($students);

$s =  html_entity_decode($students);
```

Thank you so much for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could accessing the middlename of the firts row this way

```
$st = json_decode( $students);
$st[0]['middlename'];


var_dump( $st[0]['middlename']);
```